# Docker Compose help. Moving the docker-compose file up one level

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've checked out this project [sawtooth-core](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-core)  and I'm struggling to to move the docker-compose.yaml up one level in my directory stack. I'm missing something about how to update the directory references to get it to execute in the same way.   I have included the before and after of my changes with the containing folder of the repo:

```
root
- new docker-compose.yaml here
---->sawtooth-core
      - old docker-compose.yaml
```

this is the from
    version: '3.6'

```
services:

  settings-tp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: families/settings/Dockerfile
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-settings-tp-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-local
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        cd families/settings/sawtooth_settings
        cargo build --release
        mkdir -p bin
        cp target/release/settings-tp bin/settings-tp
        settings-tp -vv -C tcp://validator:4004
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  client:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/sawtooth-shell
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-shell-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-local
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth keygen &&
        tail -f /dev/null
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  validator:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: validator/Dockerfile
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-validator-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-local
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 8800
      - 5050
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    # start the validator with an empty genesis batch
    command: |
      bash -c "
        bin/protogen
        cd validator
        python3 setup.py clean --all
        python3 setup.py build
        mkdir -p bin
        mkdir -p lib
        cargo build --release
        cp ./target/release/sawtooth-validator bin/sawtooth-validator
        cp ./target/release/libsawtooth_validator.so lib/libsawtooth_validator.so
        sawadm keygen
        sawset genesis \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          -o config-genesis.batch && \
        sawset proposal create \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=Devmode \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=0.1 \
          -o config.batch && \
        sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch && \
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
            --endpoint tcp://validator:8800 \
            --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
            --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
            --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  rest-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: rest_api/Dockerfile
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-rest-api-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-local
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        bin/protogen
        cd rest_api
        python3 setup.py clean --all
        python3 setup.py build
        sawtooth-rest-api -v --connect tcp://validator:4004 --bind rest-api:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  devmode-rust:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
        devmode-engine-rust -v --connect tcp://validator:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  intkey-tp-python:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        intkey-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator:4004
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  xo-tp-python:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator:4004
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
```

to

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  settings-tp:
    build:
      context: ./sawtooth-core
      dockerfile: sawtooth-core/families/settings/Dockerfile
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxyß
    image: sawtooth-settings-tp-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./sawtooth-core/:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-local
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        cd families/settings/sawtooth_settings
        cargo build --release
        mkdir -p bin
        cp target/release/settings-tp bin/settings-tp
        settings-tp -vv -C tcp://validator:4004
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  client:
    build:
      context: ./sawtooth-core
      dockerfile: sawtooth-core/docker/sawtooth-shell
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-shell-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./sawtooth-core/:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-local
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth keygen &&
        tail -f /dev/nullß
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  validator:
    build:
      context: ./sawtooth-core
      dockerfile: sawtooth-core/validator/Dockerfile
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-validator-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./sawtooth-core/:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-local
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 8800
      - 5050
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    # start the validator with an empty genesis batch
    command: |
      bash -c "
        bin/protogen
        cd validator
        python3 setup.py clean --all
        python3 setup.py build
        mkdir -p bin
        mkdir -p lib
        cargo build --release
        cp ./target/release/sawtooth-validator bin/sawtooth-validator
        cp ./target/release/libsawtooth_validator.so lib/libsawtooth_validator.so
        sawadm keygen
        sawset genesis \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          -o config-genesis.batch && \
        sawset proposal create \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.name=Devmode \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm.version=0.1 \
          -o config.batch && \
        sawadm genesis config-genesis.batch config.batch && \
        sawtooth-validator -vv \
            --endpoint tcp://validator:8800 \
            --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
            --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
            --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  rest-api:
    build:
      context: ./sawtooth-core
      dockerfile: sawtooth-core/rest_api/Dockerfile
      args:
        - http_proxy
        - https_proxy
        - no_proxy
    image: sawtooth-rest-api-local:${ISOLATION_ID}
    volumes:
      - ./sawtooth-core/:/project/sawtooth-core
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-local
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        bin/protogen
        cd rest_api
        python3 setup.py clean --all
        python3 setup.py build
        sawtooth-rest-api -v --connect tcp://validator:4004 --bind rest-api:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  devmode-rust:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-devmode-engine-rust
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
        devmode-engine-rust -v --connect tcp://validator:5050
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  intkey-tp-python:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-intkey-tp-python:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-intkey-tp-python
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        intkey-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator:4004
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL

  xo-tp-python:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-xo-tp-python:nightly
    container_name: sawtooth-xo-tp-python
    depends_on:
      - validator
    command: |
      bash -c "
        xo-tp-python -vv -C tcp://validator:4004
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
```

The issue is that it sits here indefinitely

```
devmode-rust uses an image, skipping
intkey-tp-python uses an image, skipping
xo-tp-python uses an image, skipping
Building validator
```

Building Validator**<---- assuming the issue is happening here (most of the images have a dependancy on this guy)**

Comment: What's the question? What error are you running into?

Comment: I updated the question. I was in a rush when I posted this (thanks for calling me out on it)

Comment: Do you get the same results if you delete all of the other containers in the `docker-compose.yml` file?  And the rather long shell script you've embedded as that container's `command:`?  If so, can you trim down the sample code you've included to only the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem?